# What does 'attorney' mean in this passage from The Winter's Tale

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs, early-modern-english, shakespeare

In *[The Winter's Tale](https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/WT_F1/complete/index.html)*, it is written:

> Cam. Sicilia cannot shew himselfe ouer-kind to Bohe-
> mia: They were trayn'd together in their Child-hoods;
> and there rooted betwixt them then such an affection,
> which cannot chuse but braunch now. Since their more
> mature Dignities, and Royall Necessities, made seperati-
> on of their Societie, their Encounters (though not Perso-
> nall) hath been Royally **attornyed** with enter-change of
> Gifts, Letters, louing Embassies, that they haue seem'd to
> be together, though absent: shooke hands, as ouer a Vast;
> and embrac'd as it were from the ends of opposed Winds.
> The Heauens continue their Loues.

I looked up *[attorney](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attorney#Verb)* in a dictionary
but methinks Wiktionary's definitions do not
describe the meaning of this verb in this context.
What does *attorney* mean in this passage?

Comment: I'm going with *represented*.

Comment: There's at least one website that claims to tell what all Shakespeare's words mean. You might like to research it a bit more though. https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Play.aspx?WorkId=35 https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Glossary.aspx?id=319

Comment: [The full OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/12892?rskey=iQ4EoO&result=1#eid34373226) defines this sense under *attorney, verb* (with the same citation) as *transitive. To **send a representative** to (a meeting) on one's behalf. **Apparently an isolated use.*** That's a separate sense to *(Obsolete. rare.) transitive. **To appoint (someone) as one's legal representative or proxy; to make an attorney.***

Comment: Upvoted for getting into the spirit with "methinks".

Comment: “lawyered up”!...

Comment: @TinfoilHat - This is _attorney_ in the sense of _legal representative or proxy_, not in the American sense _lawyer_. The gifts and letters were exchanged through third parties.